# Create a new row based on criteria

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am pulling a set of information for a Check Summary Report and I am running into an issue where I need to display the full history of the check. In particular, say for instance I have issued a Check. This check can possibly be Voided. If it is Voided in our program, it will simply change the Status of the check to Void. However, I need instead to be able to create a new row entry and manipulate the data accordingly.

Here is the query I am working with.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    O.GFNo AS 'FileNumber'
    ,CASE
        WHEN C.VoidDate IS NOT NULL
            THEN C.VoidDate
        WHEN C.VoidDate IS NULL
            THEN C.CheckDate
        ELSE NULL
        END AS 'Date'
    -- Check type descriptions.
    ,CASE
        WHEN C.CheckStatus NOT IN (3,4) AND C.VoidDate IS NULL
            THEN CASE 
                WHEN C.IsTransfer = 0 AND C.IsWire = 0 AND C.IsEFER = 0
                    THEN 'Check'
                WHEN C.IsTransfer = 1
                    THEN 'Transfer'
                WHEN C.IsWire = 1
                    THEN 'Wire'
                WHEN C.IsEFER = 1
                    THEN 'EFER'
                END
        -- Stopped checks.
        WHEN C.CheckStatus = 3 AND C.VoidDate IS NOT NULL
            THEN CASE
                WHEN C.IsTransfer = 0 AND C.IsWire = 0 AND C.IsEFER = 0
                    THEN 'Stopped Check'
                WHEN C.IsTransfer = 1
                    THEN 'Stopped Transfer'
                WHEN C.IsWire = 1
                    THEN 'Stopped Wire'
                WHEN C.IsEFER = 1
                    THEN 'Stopped EFER'
                END
        -- Voided checks.
        WHEN C.CheckStatus = 4 AND C.VoidDate IS NOT NULL
            THEN CASE
                WHEN C.IsTransfer = 0 AND C.IsWire = 0 AND C.IsEFER = 0
                    THEN 'Void Check'
                WHEN C.IsTransfer = 1
                    THEN 'Void Transfer'
                WHEN C.IsWire = 1
                    THEN 'Void Wire'
                WHEN C.IsEFER = 1
                    THEN 'Void EFER'
                END
        END AS 'Description'
    -- Check number.
    ,CASE 
        WHEN C.IsTransfer = 1
            THEN 'XFer'
        WHEN C.IsConsolidated = 1 AND C.ConsolidatedCheckID > 0 
            THEN 'Consolidated'
        WHEN C.IsEFER = 1
            THEN 'EFER-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), C.WireNumber)
        WHEN C.IsWire = 1
            THEN 'W-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), C.WireNumber)
        WHEN C.IsCashiersCheck = 1
            THEN 'C-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), C.CheckNumber)
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), C.CheckNumber)
        END AS 'CheckNumber'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 0) AS 'Receipts'
    ,CASE
        WHEN C.CheckStatus = 4 AND C.VoidDate IS NOT NULL 
            THEN ISNULL(C.Amount, 0)
        ELSE CAST(0.0 - C.Amount AS MONEY)
        END AS 'Disbursements'
FROM 
    Checks C
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Orders O
        ON C.OrdersID = O.OrdersID
    LEFT JOIN CheckSessionDetail CSD
        ON C.ChecksID = CSD.ChecksID
        AND CSD.ActionType IN (6,9)
    LEFT JOIN CheckSession CS
        ON CSD.CheckSessionID = CS.CheckSessionID
WHERE
    O.OrdersID = @OrdersID
    AND C.CheckDate IS NOT NULL
```

This is what it is returning. If the check is Voided, it will simply change the Description to 'Void.'

```
| FileNumber |    Date   | Description | CheckNumber | Receipts | Disbursements |
|     1      |  8/8/2014 |    Check    |    1001     |    0     |    $7500      |
|     1      |  8/8/2014 |    Check    |    1002     |    0     |    $5000      |
|     1      |  8/8/2014 |    Void     |    1003     |    0     |    $1000      |
```

This is how I NEED it to return:

```
| FileNumber |    Date   | Description | CheckNumber | Receipts | Disbursements |
|     1      |  8/8/2014 |    Check    |    1001     |    0     |    $7500      |
|     1      |  8/8/2014 |    Check    |    1002     |    0     |    $5000      |
|     1      |  8/8/2014 |    Check    |    1003     |    0     |    $1000      |
|     1      |  8/8/2014 |    Void     |    1003     |  $1000   |      $0       |
```

Notice how if the check was voided, it retains the initial Check entry, but ALSO creates a Void entry and places the dollar amount into the Receipts column. It will also persist the same CheckNumber.

Essentially, is it possible to say something along the lines of: If a Check has the status of Void, create a new row entry? I'm thinking that a temporary table might work, but I've not delved too much into them. I've been banging my head trying to figure this out all day long, so any and all help you guys could offer would be a tremendous help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, instead of:

```
FROM Checks C
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Orders O ...
```

try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    O.GFNo AS 'FileNumber'
    ,c.Date
    ...
FROM ( select Date = CheckDate, typ = 'Check', * from Checks
       UNION ALL
       select Date = VoidDate, typ = 'Void', * from Checks WHERE VoidDate is not null ) c
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Orders O ...
```

and use `typ` in your case statements for `Description`, `Receipts`, etc.